# none of us is as smart as all of us

Tags: translation, usage, proverbs

This proverb is attributed to an unknown Japanese author (http://thinkexist.com/quotation/none_of_us_are_as_smart_as_all_of/160488.html). However I could not find any mention of its actual origin.

Would anybody here be able to translate the sentence or its spirit? I would like to use it for a presentation at work.

Comment: This appears to be the following 名言: http://meigen-search.net/d/MQLkAGN5

Comment: Hi @virmaior: thanks, looks good, can you post it as an answer so I can validate it?

Comment: The page virmaior linked says it's from ミッチェル・ノラン, who seems to be a British judge in the 20th century. And according to [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29917/origin-of-everybody-is-smarter-than-anybody), this proverb(?) seems to originate from Western countries somewhere in the 18-19th century. I doubt there is a Japanese traditional proverb which is widely recognized and can be directly translated to this, although there is a [similar one](https://ja.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E4%B8%89%E4%BA%BA%E5%AF%84%E3%82%8C%E3%81%B0%E6%96%87%E6%AE%8A%E3%81%AE%E7%9F%A5%E6%81%B5).

Comment: The attribution to Talleyrand in the English.SE answer seems most likely to be correct to me, since this doesn't sound as mellifluous in Japanese.

Comment: This is probably another case of "not an actual Japanese proverb" :-(

Comment: I tried to add a [Proverb] tag, and was told that the tag doesn't exist. Very odd.

Comment: Hi @naruto: 三人寄れば文殊の知恵 seems indeed good enough. As there does not seem to be anything close would you please post it as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think 三人寄れば文殊の知恵 (lit. "If three people gather, the wisdom of [Monju](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manjushri) (is achieved)") is the closest proverb in Japanese.

I'm not aware of any Japanese set phrase that can literally translate to "None of us are as smart as all of us".